# Jenkins pipeline - git branch

Tags: git, jenkins, branch, jenkins-pipeline

I am writing pipeline script in order to implement continuous integration flow in our project. The process is for users to do work in a specific branch that follows naming convention, `test_id1`, `test_id2` etc. Once these are pushed to remote repo, Jenkins kicks-in, it checks out branch with test* and does rest of the build process.

Based on my initial instinct, I wrote the pipeline script as follows:
stage 'build'

```
node {
    git url: 'git@hd1:testing', branch: test*
    sh "pwd"
    sh "cat simple.csh"
    sh "echo $PATH"
    sh "csh simple.csh"
    echo("end of pipeline")
}
```

Btw, I have tried "test*", 'test*'.

Jenkins bails out with the following error:

```
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git checkout -b test* 264dc398372cba41c026568bd764d2656ebfc511" returned status code 128:
```

So, the question is whether I am going in the right direction with this.
I also looked at the error above and obviously, git checkout with a wildcard is something that would not serve the purpose. So, would the following approach work:

1) Checkout git master as usual
2) Check if any new branch by the name test* exists
3) If it does, checkout the branch and then do rest of the build

Need some directions on this ...

Comment: Try the pipeline's `checkout` step and use `:<regex>` as branch name (the colon is important here to let jenkins know you are using a regex!). Checkout the Snippet Generator in your Jenkins instance - it can help you with the step's syntax

Answer (score 2):

You can use SCM checkout plugin with regular expression. I've used to poll the feature branches with the format feature/US1234. Modify like you need.

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
branches: [[name: ':^(?i)origin/feature/[a-z|A-Z]{2}[0-9].*']], 
doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
extensions: [[$class: 'WipeWorkspace'], 
[$class: 'LocalBranch', localBranch: '**']], submoduleCfg: [], 
userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'YOURID', url: 'GITURL']]])
```

Use pipeline syntax generator for more option.